# How to use PCI Express serial card under Debian Jessie, on ARMv71?

Tags: drivers, pci-express, debian-jessie, arm

I'm running Debian Jessie on my Hummingboard, an iMX6-based ARM SBC.

```
root@torpedo:~# uname -a
Linux torpedo 4.11.4-cubox #2 SMP Tue Jun 13 14:51:52 CEST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

It's got a mini PCI express slot, which I plan to use for a 4 port UART card. I've got a [card from Diamond systems which uses the EXAR XR17V354 UART chip](http://diamondsystems.com/products/dsmpeser4m).

Being an optimist, I plugged in the card and booted, hoping for the best.

Looks like the card is recognized:

```
root@torpedo:~# lspci -v
00:00.0 PCI bridge: Synopsys, Inc. Device abcd (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal deco             de])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Memory at 01000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: 01100000-011fffff
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 01200000 [disabled] [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

01:00.0 Serial controller: Exar Corp. Device 0354 (rev 03) (prog-if 02 [16550])
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 334
        Memory at 01100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [80] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
        Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
```

However, **dmesg** contains no mention of ttys created at boot time, other than the GPIO ones associated with the Hummingboard, which have always been there.

The vendor (Diamond) provides a custom driver, which i downloaded and built from source. 
When I load the **.ko**, **dmesg** says:

```
[  640.564446] DSMPESER4MDriver: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[  640.565123] The init fun get called
[  640.565199] pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0140 -> 0142)
[  640.565359] DS-MPE-SER4M driver loaded
```

And **/var/log/messages** says:

```
root@torpedo:~# tail -f /var/log/messages
...
Apr 17 15:48:50 torpedo kernel: DSMPESER4MDriver: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
Apr 17 15:48:50 torpedo kernel: The init fun get called
Apr 17 15:48:50 torpedo kernel: pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0140 -> 0142)
Apr 17 15:48:50 torpedo kernel: DS-MPE-SER4M driver loaded
```

A few questions:

1. How do I fix "loading out-of-tree module taints kernel."? (not a technical issue - see comment)
2. How do I use **mknod** to create the **/dev/tty** files for this driver?
3. How do I configure the module to load at boot time?

Comment: When the kernel is tainted, it means that it is in a state that is not supported by the community. Most kernel developers will ignore bug reports involving tainted kernels, and community members may ask that you correct the tainting condition before they can proceed with diagnosing problems related to the kernel. In addition, some debugging functionality and API calls may be disabled when the kernel is tainted.

Comment: Update: the EXAR site has a better driver, and doc. Their doc states that this chipset is supported in the kernel. After investigation, looks like modern kernels support a fixed number of serial devices: 4 by default. Rebuilding my kernel with a higher number to support all my UARTs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [EXAR documentation](https://www.exar.com/design-tools/software-drivers) was correct. This board *is* supported by modern Linux kernels. This issue for me was that my kernel was configured to support only 4 serial ports, total.

On the Hummingboard, the on-chip UARTs were using up the first 4 UARTs. I reconfigured the kernel for 16 serial ports, max. Rebuilt my kernel following [debian-specific method](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/i386/ch08s06.html.en). Rebooted.

```
root@torpedo:~# uname -a
Linux torpedo 4.16.2whoi-armhf #1 SMP Wed Apr 18 16:56:21 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

New kernel installed and running...check the PCI bus:

```
root@torpedo:~# lspci -vv
...
01:00.0 Serial controller: Exar Corp. Device 0354 (rev 03) (prog-if 02 [16550])
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr+ Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 334
        Region 0: Memory at 01100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold-)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [80] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 01
                DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
                        ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
                DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
                        RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk-
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk- DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
                LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
                         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
                LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
                         EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
                Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
                Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
                Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
                Status: InProgress-
                VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
                        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
                        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
                        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        Kernel driver in use: exar_serial
```

Looks like I didn't break the PCI bus.

Did the kernel find the UARTs?

```
root@torpedo:~# dmesg|grep tty
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait console=tty1 consoleblank=0 video=mxcfb0:dev=hdmi,1920x1080m60,if=RGB24,bpp=32 rd.dm=0 rd.luks=0 rd.lvm=0 raid=noautodetect pci=nomsi vt.global_cursor_default=0 loglevel=1
[    0.001375] console [tty1] enabled
[    1.220660] 0000:01:00.0: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x1100000 (irq = 334, base_baud = 7812500) is a XR17V35X
[    1.221093] 0000:01:00.0: ttyS1 at MMIO 0x1100400 (irq = 334, base_baud = 7812500) is a XR17V35X
[    1.221498] 0000:01:00.0: ttyS2 at MMIO 0x1100800 (irq = 334, base_baud = 7812500) is a XR17V35X
[    1.221896] 0000:01:00.0: ttyS3 at MMIO 0x1100c00 (irq = 334, base_baud = 7812500) is a XR17V35X
[    1.222587] 2020000.serial: ttymxc0 at MMIO 0x2020000 (irq = 26, base_baud = 5000000) is a IMX
[    1.223350] 21ec000.serial: ttymxc2 at MMIO 0x21ec000 (irq = 70, base_baud = 5000000) is a IMX
[    1.224122] 21f0000.serial: ttymxc3 at MMIO 0x21f0000 (irq = 71, base_baud = 5000000) is a IMX
```

Cool. Works.